# fetch dosent bring any data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, api

when i use fetch  to bring the list of notes and consol.log it nothing shows up. The url is not wrong i have carefully checked it. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const NotesListPage = () => {

    let [notes, setNotes] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

    }, [])

    let getNotes = async () => {
        let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notes/')
        let data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        setNotes(data)
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotesListPage
```

here is the api part:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getNotes(request):
    notes = Note.objects.all()
    serializer = NoteSerializer(notes, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You never even call your `getNotes` function.

Comment: its a silly mistake or you are actually getting the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const NotesListPage = () => {

    let [notes, setNotes] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
         getNotes();
    }, [])

    let getNotes = async () => {
        let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notes/')
        let data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        setNotes(data)
    } 

    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotesListPage
```

Comment: oh my god! i think i am slowly losing my brain how did i not see that. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling your function 'getNotes'

The way I would do it, it to fetch your data in the Effect hook and set it in your state hook there.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const NotesListPage = () => {

    let [notes, setNotes] = useState([])

    useEffect( async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/notes/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            setNotes(response)
    }, [])

    console.log(notes)

    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotesListPage
```

*Edit

Cleaner would be to have the fetch in a seperate function doing the same thing and just calling that function in your effect hook (see other answer above*)

Comment: Thanks alot cant belive i am this dumb